# printing line breaks using sprintf - with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make line breaks when printing.

here is my code:

```
temp <- LETTERS[1:11]

print(sprintf("Rank %s = %s \n", 1:11, temp))
```

output:

```
[1] "Rank 1 = A \n"  "Rank 2 = B \n"  "Rank 3 = C \n"  "Rank 4 = D \n"  "Rank 5 = E \n"  "Rank 6 = F \n"  "Rank 7 = G \n"  "Rank 8 = H \n"  "Rank 9 = I \n" 
[10] "Rank 10 = J \n" "Rank 11 = K \n"
```

I naively thought that `\n` made a line break.  My desired output would be:

```
"Rank 1 = A"  
"Rank 2 = B"  
"Rank 3 = C"  
"Rank 4 = D"  
... etc.
```

**EDIT:**

Pascal's comment tells me that it works with `cat`

```
cat(sprintf("Rank %s = %s \n", 1:11, temp))
```

I'm using this code inside of `renderText` inside shiny.  `print` will return text, but I cannot get `cat` to return text.

In this case, is there anywhere to generate the required line breaks, without using `cat`?

Comment: It works with `cat` instead of `print`.

Comment: oh, right... that actually leads to a separate question ... i shall edit.

Comment: @akrun renderPrint will return text when using `cat` - but unfortunately the text are returned as if they are a vector, i.e. the line breaks don't show up in the shiny output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `writeLines` to introduce line breaks as given below:

```
temp <- LETTERS[1:11]
writeLines(sprintf("Rank %s = %s", 1:11, temp))
Rank 1 = A
Rank 2 = B
Rank 3 = C
Rank 4 = D
Rank 5 = E
Rank 6 = F
Rank 7 = G
Rank 8 = H
Rank 9 = I
Rank 10 = J
Rank 11 = K
```

You can also use `print` with `writeLines` but it will give you a NULL at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cat` in a `renderPrint` statement, to render in the UI with `verbatimTextOutput`.

Another option is to use HTML with some `<br/>` to break the lines:

```
renderUI({
  HTML(paste0(sprintf("Rank %s = %s", 1:11, temp), collapse = "<br/>"))
})
```

to render in the UI with `uiOutput`.