# how to remove "\n"in sprintf() in r?

Tags: r

i am creating a text by using `sprintf()` in `R`, but the output receives `\n`, how can i remove it?

```
question <- sprintf("Can you interpret the results :\n
                     Threshold: %f\n
                     Sensitivity: %f\n
                     Specificity: %f\n
                     PPV: %f\n
                     NPV: %f\n
                     Accuracy: %f", roc_table$threshold, roc_table$sensitivity, 
                    roc_table$specificty, roc_table$ppv, roc_table$npv, roc_table$accuracy)
```

`output`

[1] "Can you interpret the results in the ROC analysis for:\n\n                     Threshold: 2.500000\n\n                     Sensitivity: 0.890000\n\n                     Specificity: 0.650000\n\n                     PPV: 0.230000\n\n                     NPV: 0.540000\n\n                     Accuracy: 0.230000"

Comment: You can wrap `sprintf` with `cat` (`cat(sprintf(...))`) (maybe you can drop the `\n` character in your `sprintf`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printing line breaks using sprintf - with shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757372/printing-line-breaks-using-sprintf-with-shiny)